# How to log all requests to ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a problem with debugging my application,
so I would like to log all the requests that are send to Elasticsearch.

I learnt that I can do this via slowlog by setting the *long* time to `0s`.

I tried this both in `ES 2.4.2` and in `ES 5.6.4`, but no requests were logged.

In `ES 2.4.2` I set in `logging.yml`:

```
  index.search.slowlog: INFO, index_search_slow_log_file
  index.indexing.slowlog: INFO, index_indexing_slow_log_file
```

In `ES 5.6.4` I also changed the level to INFO (in `log4j2.properties`):

```
logger.index_search_slowlog_rolling.level = info
logger.index_indexing_slowlog.level = info
```

Then I started ES and issued:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/com.example.app.model.journal/_settings' -d '
{
    "index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info" : "0s", 
    "index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.info": "0s", 
    "index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.info": "0s" 
}
'
```

(I would prefer to set this settings for all indexes in configuration
file, is it possible?)

Then I searched for some data (and got results):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/com.example.app.model.journal/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query":
    {
        "match" : { "rank" : "2" } }
    }
}'
```

This requests was not logged, in `ES 2.4.2` the slowlog files are created
and empty, in `ES 5.6.4` files are not created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a solution to this, so as a workaround I used [mitmdump](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/mitmdump.html). Run the proxy:

```
 mitmdump -v -dddd -R http://localhost:9200
```

Replace the ES address with the proxy address:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:8080/com.example.app.model.journal/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    ...
```